# Including pip-installed libraries on emacs python shell

Tags: python, shell

I recently found out you can run python from emacs (Python Mode -> py-shell) and I've been running my scripts through the py-shell due to only needing to C-c C-c, but I've been running into a problem:

I `import requests` among other external libraries I have installed (through pip), but the python shell in Emacs can't find the modules. Is there a way I can change PATH variables in such a way that Emacs finds these modules?

Here's the error the python shell gives (not sure if it helps, but this runs on the "Py:run Shell-Compile" buffer):

```
exec(compile(open(r'/Users/r/Desktop/name.py').read(), r'/Users/r/Desktop/name.py', 'exec')) # PYTHON-MODE
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/r/Desktop/name.py", line 1, in <module>
    import requests
ImportError: No module named requests
```

(As proof that I do have requests installed, I ran this on the terminal with `python name.py` and it worked as expected)

Comment: Looks like a bug. Please follow up here: https://gitlab.com/python-mode-devs/python-mode/issues/32

Comment: Which operating system?  See [`exec-path-from-shell`](https://github.com/purcell/exec-path-from-shell), which might help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7143077/how-can-i-install-packages-in-my-home-folder-with-pip